# Telugu text showing as square boxes in web-page. How to show original text?

Tags: html, ubuntu, web, browser, character-encoding

I have one HTML web page where telugu text is showing as square boxes as below image (in all browser):

ఠిస్ ఐస్ ఆ తెలుగు టెక్స్ట్

Below code is already there in head tag of web page. If i place hindi text it will display on page perfectly.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Also, on page load in chorme it ask for google translage and it translate in englist perfectly, which means google translater is able to read telugu but browser/HTML is not able to show it.

Note: Its happening only on linux based OS (ubuntu).

I am missing anything on web-page or its a default behaviour of OS?

Comment: Change your browser language

Comment: Share your html code here

Comment: Simple : In $HOME → `mkdir .fonts` ... and copy the fonts to `.fonts/` . ... You can also do e.g. `sudo cp Lohit-Telugu.ttf /usr/share/fonts/TTF/`, etc. etc. fonts. .... And then read "the news paper" http://www.eenadu.net/ in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your browser language -

> chrome://settings/ Advanced / Languages / Add languages

- Search Tel
- Add

It might be resolved your problem

Comment: Tried this but could not work. I have not added hindi as a language in chrome but i can see hindi words perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-indic
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.